# Fitting data points while forcing the shape of the curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-fitting

I'm trying to fit 2D data points with a polynomial curve; see the picture below. The blue points are the data. The blue, dashed line is a 2<sup>nd</sup> order polynomial fit to these points. I want to force my fit to have exactly the same shape as the black line, and I want to compute the y offset of the new fit from the black curve. Any ideas on how this would be possible? Thanks in advance.

```
x = np.linspace(6.0,12.0,num=100)

a = -0.0864
b = 11.18
c = 9.04
fit_y = a*(x - b)**2 + c # black line

z = np.polyfit(data_x,data_y,2)

zfit=z[2]+z[1]*x+z[0]*x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data_x,data_y,'.',color='b')
ax.plot(x,fit_y,color='black') #curve of which we want the shape
ax.plot(x,zfit,color='blue',linestyle='dashed') #polynomial fit
ax.set_xlim([6.5,11.0])
ax.set_ylim([6.5,10.5])
plt.show()
```

[image: data points and desired fit shape]

Edit: This is the solution to my problem:

```
x = np.linspace(6.0,12.0,num=100)

# We want to keep a and b fixed to keep the same shape
# a = -0.0864     
# b = 11.18
c = 9.04

#Only c is a variable because we only want to shift the plot on the y axis
def f(x, c):
    return -0.0864*(x - 11.18)**2 + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, data_x, data_y)  # popt are the fitted parameters

plt.plot(data_x, data_y,'.') #blue data points
plt.plot(x,f(x, c),'black') #black line, this is the shape we want our fit to have

plt.plot(x, f(x, *popt), 'red')  # new fitted line to the data (with same shape as black line)

plt.xlim([6.5,11.0])
plt.ylim([6.5,10.5])

plt.show()

print("y offset:", popt[0] - c)
```

y offset: 0.23492393887717355

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv85S.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show us what you have tried so far? In particular regarding how you're trying to find the fit. Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you! I have tried a 2nd order polynomial fit but I'm clueless as to how to force a shape on this fit. I have edited my post with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). As you can see in the documentation, you can define your own function `fit_y` with the parameters to fit. Once the fit is done, you can compute the y offset (respect to the origin?) simply calculating the function in `x=0`. Below I show you an example code where I used a root function (this is what your black curve looks like):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.power(x, b) + c


x_data = np.arange(100)
noise = np.random.normal(size=100)
y_data = np.power(x_data, 0.5) + noise
y = f(x_data, 1, 2, 0.3)  # random values to initialize the fit
popt, _ = curve_fit(f, x_data, y_data)  # popt are the fitted parameters

plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
plt.plot(x_data, f(x_data, *popt), 'r')  # fitted line
plt.show()

print("y offset:", f(0, *popt))
```

I don't have enough reputation to post the plot, but just run the code to see yourself.

Comment: Why would you say `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` is better than `numpy.polyfit` for this purpose? Does this answer the question at all?

Comment: As Druton said "I want to force my fit to have EXACTLY the same shape as the black line". In order to do that, he must know the functional form f(x) of the curve. Even if any function can be rewritten as a polynomial (Taylor), why guess the degree of the polynomial, when one can simply fit the coefficients in f(x)?

Comment: I see, so you assume that the functional dependence of the black line is known. Not sure if that assumption is justified, but OP isn't really clear about that point.

Comment: Yes the distribution of the black line is known: a*(x - b)**2 + c where a = -0.0864, b = 11.18, c = 9.04.

Comment: Thanks Logozoe. I figured it out with your help. I only needed to use the curve_fit for the c parameter, while keeping a and b fixed.